# Action Bar Sherlock dropdown spinner divider

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I hide dividers in action bar dropdown menu navigation? 
Here is divider which I want to hide:

http://s10.postimage.org/4sjqjxltl/4nk4k.png

I tried following in styles:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg_shape</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bg_shape</item>

    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0px</item>

</style>



<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg_shape</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/actionbar_dropdown_bg_shape</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/dropdown_nav_selector</item>

    <item name="android:dropDownWidth">175dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHeight">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0px</item>


    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bg_shape</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Test.ICS" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
   <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
   <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <item name="actionBarDivider">@drawable/icon</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/icon</item>

</style>
```

I've also tried with changing divider property to color or drawable.
But divider is still present in dropdown menu navigation, no effect at all. Any ideas would be really helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You need to extend the Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown style like this:

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/YourThemeDropDownListView</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/YourThemeDropDownListView</item>
</style>

<style name="YourThemeDropDownListView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: By overriding this listdown style. Is it possible to change the style of the divider as well?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth to note, that divider Height must be specified to edit divider's color.

```
<style name="YourThemeDropDownListView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@color/White</item
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">5dp</item>
</style>
```